# Concept for Implementing a Manual Background Removal Feature

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I'm working on creating an image background removal app, and I've noticed that many APIs and ML kits are available for this purpose. However, not all of them are 100% accurate. Therefore, I'm considering implementing a manual background removal feature. Can someone please share insights on the actual concept behind manual background removal? Alternatively, if you have any codebase or Git repository links related to this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.